# I m Adding ArrayList in FirebaseAppIndex but not able to search all list items from Google Search

Tags: android, firebase

I want to search app content from Google. I m adding ArrayList in FirebaseAppIndex but not able to search all list items from Google Search, I can able to search only the last item of arraylist.

```
    ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    titleList.add("ABC");
    titleList.add("DEF");
    titleList.add("GHI");
    titleList.add("KLM");
    ArrayList<Indexable> indexableNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titleList.size(); i++) {
        Indexable noteToIndex = Indexables.noteDigitalDocumentBuilder()
                .setName(titleList.get(i) + " Note")
                .setText("Pierogi")
                .setUrl("http://recipe-app.com/recipe/pierogi-poutine")
                .build();
        Log.d("onHandleIntent", "update");
        indexableNotes.add(noteToIndex);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < indexableNotes.size(); i++) {
        Indexable[] notesArr = new Indexable[indexableNotes.size()];
        notesArr = indexableNotes.toArray(notesArr);
        Log.d("update", notesArr.toString());
        FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(notesArr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is always the same URL, so they overwrite each other and only the last one wins.
(you can also use the firebase appindexing debugging UI to look at the indexed results)